# PowerShell v2 Server 2003 - Cannot Find Path - Path definitely exists

Tags: powershell, error-handling, path, windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008-r2

Usually I can find an answer to PowerShell questions by researching forums and adapting. However, after searching high and low, I cannot find an answer.

I am logged in as a domain administrator working on two enterprise servers in a test domain. $Server2003 is Windows 2003 server running PS v2. $Server2008 is Windows 2008 R2.

Problem: When I am working from $Server2003  I cannot use any commands to access or verify information on $Server2008. This error happens regardless of who the administrator is.

I have used PowerShell fairly extensively in our environments and haven't run into this error before. The error is not present when running commands from $Server2008 on $Server2003. In addition the error is not present when running commands from a production domain. I can also ping the 2003 or 2008 server regardless of which machine I am logged in as.

---

Examples:
From $Server2008: ping $Server2003 - returns pings

From $Server2003: ping $Server2008 - returns pings

From $Server2003: `test-path \\$Server2008\D$\` - Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path `'\\$Server2008\D$\'` because it does not exist

From $Server2008: `test-path \\$Server2003\D$\` - True

---

The commands I want to run are a lot more complex than test-path; however, if I cannot get the simple command to work I doubt I'll have much luck with a complex one.

The two servers have the same domain, are in the same forest, and have the same domain controllers.

Any ideas where to start?

EDIT: Wanted to add that I have tried using test path from Server2003 to a different 2008 server located in our dev environment (same domain) and it runs the test-path and commands successfully.

Comment: I don't experience this problem so I'm not to sure what to tell you.

Answer (score 0):

can you access the 2008 server remotely by other means? Like the Services MMC? Also, what if you create a share on 2008 rather than rely on the admin share?

Comment: Yeah I can RDP into both machines. However, just trying it now on the 2003, trying to create a network share to the 2008 gives me the unreachable error. Or did you mean using PSSession or WSManCredSSP? Neither of those have worked for me either.

Comment: create a share on 2008, and then try to access it from 2003. Also on 2003, Start - Run - "services.msc", then right click on the left column and connect to 2008.

Answer (score 0):

The cannot find path error means that it doesn't exist or you don't have permissions. Does it work  from a dos prompt?

UPDATE

I just noticed that you used single quotes, the variable will not expand. Enclose it in double wotes and try again

Comment: The single quotes are what PS returns. I have tried it as a variable and as the actual server name. It definitely exists... I can log into the machine with the exact same account that I use for the 2008, so i don't think it is a permissions issue. Additionally I have had our a user who has more permissions than me give it a try and we get the same issue.

Comment: Does it fail from cmdlet too?

Comment: Sorry, I meant does it fail from cmd too?

Comment: C:\WINDOWS\system32>IF EXIST \\Server2008\D$\ (ECHO It's a directory) ELSE (ECHO false)
Returned false. I tried this from Server2003 and from my own machine. I am starting to believe it is an incorrect setting on the 2008 server

Comment: Not sure if this could be this, see the last two posts: http://forum.wegotserved.com/index.php/topic/19881-unable-to-connect-to-shared-folders-or-console-but-rdp-works-fine/

Comment: You're connecting over wireless?

Comment: My laptop is lan lined in. I thought the scenario in the link was regarding the server - really just spit balling on that one. May just reload the system and see if that solves the issue.